# Error while executing h2o framework python code

Tags: python, h2o

By executing the code `h2o.connect()`

I am getting the error message

> "raise AttributeError("Attribute %s cannot be set on H2OCluster (=
>   %r)" % (k, v)) AttributeError: Attribute internal_security_enabled
>   cannot be set on H2OCluster (= False)".

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you start with `h2o.init()`? [source](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/intro.html#h2o-cluster-inspection)

Comment: I tried even h2o.init() changing the port number and ip address but still its giving the same error.

Comment: what version of python are you using?